# PHP & Mysql database updating problem

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason when I changed my php code from mysql to mysqli everything got messed up.

For example, when a user enters a rating my mysql table updates twice by entering one new row and updating the correct row. I was wondering how do I correct this problem so it only updates the new row and checks to see if there is no row it enters one?

PHP code

```
// function to insert rating
function rate(){
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $text = strip_tags($_GET['rating']);
    $update = "update vote set counter = counter + 1, value = value + ".$_GET['rating']."";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$update); 
    if(mysqli_affected_rows() == 0){
        $insert = "insert into vote (counter,value) values ('1','".$_GET['rating']."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$insert); 
    }
}
```

old php code

```
// function to insert rating
function rate(){
    $text = strip_tags($_GET['rating']);
    $update = "update vote set counter = counter + 1, value = value + ".$_GET['rating']."";

    $result = mysql_query($update); 
    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0){
        $insert = "insert into vote (counter,value) values ('1','".$_GET['rating']."')";
        $result = mysql_query($insert); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `where` clause on your update?

Comment: the code worked before until I changed mysql to mysqli.

Comment: You may be better off using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), provided you've got a column with a unique index on it (which ought to be in your missing `WHERE` clause, as in klausbyskov's comment - what you've got now will increment *every* row's `counter` value, and set the `value` value to whatever's in `$_GET['rating']`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about trying this

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) ==0){
```

Comment: This should be done automatically by the function (so says the manual). Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

You should instead combine the two statements.  This would require you to have a PRIMARY KEY, perhaps named id.

```
// function to insert rating
function rate() {
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $text = strip_tags($_GET['rating']);
    $update = sprintf('INSERT INTO vote SET
                       id = 1,
                       counter = 1,
                       value = %1$d
                       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                       counter = counter + 1,
                       value = value + %1$d',
                       $text);
    mysqli_query($dbc,$update); 
}
```